# How can I display the currency in Angular.js dynamically based on per-record data?

Tags: angularjs, currency

I need to be able to show the currency dynamically with the value. For a fixed currency, I was able to do:

```
<span id="currency-custom">{{amount | currency:'&#8377'}}</span>
```

But what if I wanted to change the currency based on what came from the server as well? In my controller I have:

```
$scope.longestRide = {
    'fromAddress': 'xxx',
    'toAddress': 'yyy',
    'mycurrency': '&#8377;',
    'cost': '238',
    'duration': '00:49:02'
    }
```

But this does not seem to work:

```
<span id="currency-custom">{{amount | currency:mycurrency}}</span>
```

How can I display the currency based on the javascript data structure?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `{{amount | currency:longestRide.mycurrency }}`?

Answer (score 0):

You should try using your filter inside ng-bing-html like this:

```
<span ng-bind-html="amount | currency:mycurrency"></span>
```

Comment: No, actually the problem is with HTML escaping. The problem with the code above is that it shows me: &#8377;238.00
I need to be able to escape '&#8377;'